# JAVA/Selenium - clicking the first button on the page works 50% of the time

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium to automate some UI clicking for a web app. One one of the pages I have several buttons leading to some details. They all have the same name, but I'm ok with clicking either one, so I'm just clicking the first one. But... sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

```
WebElement DetailsButton = setPresentElementByXpath("//input[1][@type='button' and @value='Go to Details']");
DetailsButton.click();
```

I'm using setPresentElementByXpath to dynamically wait for the element.

```
private WebElement setPresentElementByXpath(String xpath) throws Exception {
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 15))
          .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
    return myDynamicElement;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I forgot to mention where it fails. It goes through `DetailsButton.click();` without issues, but then it fails on clicking the next thing, the screenshots and logs say that the page that was supposed to be displayed after clicking the button was not there, so I'm assuming the button is not clicked.

Comment: Have you tried using `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElement(WebElement element)` instead of the presence? It may be trying to click the button before it's visible on the page but is present in the DOM.

Also why are you using XPath? XPath is very brittle and isn't helping the flakeyness I'm sure. Use CSS Selectors if possible.

Comment: The same happens with visibilityOfElement. Normally I'm using ids, but in cases I can't I'm using whatever I can. Usually it's xpath, force of habit.

Comment: Try with other way of clicking like using actions class or JavaScript executor

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting timeout exception on the next element that should be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Page load speed variation and caching might be the issue. If the element not found exception is happening, use an [Explicit Wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) for it to be clickable via [ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm)(By).

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

If the exception "another element would receive the click" is happening you can click the element directly with the [JavaScriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html). Note: The JS action has no return value (if it worked or not) and does not wait for a page load if one happens after the click, like the Selenium .click() does.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Comment: It's not a synchronization problem as I added some fixed waits in between to check for this and the error still happened. As I mentioned, element is found and visible and Selenium thinks it was clicked as it doesn't throw any errors. I'm getting timeout for the next element as it's never really loaded.